# Data binding with Oxyplot in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, oxyplot

I am struggling with several issues regarding OxyPlot in a WPF project.

First off, I can use the Plot class or the PlotView class. What is the difference between these two classes?

Ideally, I want to use data binding for the Model (or at least parts of it) and for the data.

If I use PlotView, I can use Binding for the model, something like this:

```
<oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model}"/>
```

If I use Plot, I can use data binding for the data, something like

```
<oxy:Plot>
  <oxy:Plot.Series>
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" />
  </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

I can get both of these to work, but is there a way to use Binding for both the Model and the Data?

If I use the Plot class and Binding for the data, I would at least like to use Binding for the LineColor, like this

```
<oxy:Plot>
  <oxy:Plot.Series>
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" 
                        DataFieldX="X" 
                        DataFieldY="Y"
                        StrokeThickness="2"
                        MarkerSize="0"
                        LineStyle="Solid"
                        Color="{Binding LineColor}"
                        MarkerType="None"/>
  </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

I can't get this to work at all. The curve is always green. My LineColor property is defined with the type OxyColor. Is this the wrong type?

I know that I have asked several questions in the same posting, but I think that they are very closely related.

Comment: Forget about the problem with binding the Color property. It works if you use OxyColorConverter, as in one of the example applications.

Answer (score 5):

**First off, I can use the Plot class or the PlotView class. What is the difference between these two classes?**

I think you are seeing the diference in your examples, if you want to bind to the model, you have to use `oxy:PlotView`. If you want to bind to `LineSeries`, then you will have to use `oxy:Plot` control.

**I can get both of these to work, but is there a way to use Binding for both the Model and the Data?**

No, as stated in the last sentence, you cannot bind both at the same time, but you can add lineseries to your model like this (in your example):

```
PlotModel model = new PlotModel();
List<DataPoint> Points = new List<DataPoint>();

LineSeries lineserie = new LineSeries
{
    ItemsSource = Points,
    DataFieldX = "x",
    DataFieldY = "Y",
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    MarkerSize = 0,
    LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
    Color = OxyColors.White,
    MarkerType = MarkerType.None,
};

model.Series.Add(lineserie);
```

Then you bind to the model, using `oxy:PlotView`, and that's all. If you want to modify parameters that deals with plot behaviour, you have to bind to `PlotController` property to (just in case, for future work).

**EDIT:**

Oystein Bjorke (OxyPlot creator) said this, answering both questions:

> The `PlotView` component is now similar on all platforms, it contains only `Model` and `Controller` properties. The `Plot` control let you define axes, series, annotations etc. and this should only be available in XAML-based platforms.